# Radical representation of $\cos\frac {2\pi}{11}$

Tags: trigonometry, galois-theory, quintics

I want to find radical representation of $\cos\dfrac {2\pi}{11}$.

#### My attempt

Consider the 11th root of unity:

$$
\begin{aligned}
ω&= e^{2πi/11}\\
ω^n&=ω^{n\bmod 11}
\end{aligned}
$$

From Euler's formula:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(ω^1+ω^{10}\right)\\
\cos\frac{4\pi}{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(ω^2+ω^9\right)\\
\cos\frac{6\pi}{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(ω^3+ω^8\right)\\
\cos\frac{8\pi}{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(ω^4+ω^7\right)\\
\cos\frac{10\pi}{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(ω^5+ω^6\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Define

$$ω^{a,b,c, \cdots} = ω^a + ω^b + ω^c + \cdots$$

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
σ_{0}
&=ω^{\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}}=-1
\end{aligned}
$$

and

$$
\begin{aligned}
σ_{1}&=ω^{\{1,10\}}\\
σ_{2}&=ω^{\{2,9\}}\\
σ_{3}&=ω^{\{3,8\}}\\
σ_{4}&=ω^{\{4,7\}}\\
σ_{5}&=ω^{\{5,6\}}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

With

$$
\begin{aligned}
σ_1+σ_2+σ_3+σ_4+σ_5&=σ_0 \\
\sum_{\rm{cycle}}{σ_i σ_j}&=4σ_0 \\
\sum_{\rm{cycle}}{σ_i σ_j σ_k}&=10+7σ_0 \\
\sum_{\rm{cycle}}{σ_i σ_j σ_k σ_m}&=10+7σ_0 \\
σ_1 σ_2 σ_3 σ_4 σ_5&=2+3σ_0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

According to Vieta's formulas, $(σ_{1},σ_{2},σ_{3},σ_{4},σ_{5})$ is the root of $x^5+x^4-4 x^3-3 x^2+3 x+1$.

This is a solvable quintic equation, but I don't know how to solve the radical.

Comment: The solution is provided here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978035/solving-for-the-roots-of-a-solvable-quintic/1978061

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977414/simplifying-a-radical-trigonometric-expression-for-the-hendecagon-angle?noredirect=1) is also very much related. And yes this quintic equation should be solvable.

Comment: See the interesting answer of D.Matthew here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4323392/305862. See as well these two references
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841710/305862 ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3851501/305862

Comment: See as well page 15 of [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262991453_On_the_construction_of_the_regular_hendecagon_by_marked_ruler_and_compass/)

Comment: A last reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n) ...

Comment: Work Wolfram code: `Factor[x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1, 
 Extension -> Cos[1/5 ArcCos[1/22 Sqrt[1/22 (5523 + 2225 Sqrt[5])]]]]`

Comment: see  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf   for how it gets done,  and many many examples in https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tafeln_complexer_Primzahlen/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false    **and**  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996552/any-more-cyclic-quintics  **and**  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$
\sum_{k=1}^5\left(10\cos\frac{2 k π i}{11}+1\right)=0
$$

Equivalent to solving the equation:

$$\frac{x^5}{11}=10x^3+5x^2-210x-89=0$$

Its 5 roots $x_i$ can be obtained by combining the 4 roots $ζ_i$ of the resolvent.

$$
x^4+89⋅11x^3+351⋅11^3x^2+89⋅11^6⋅x+11^{10}=0
$$

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
ω&= e^{2πi/5}\\
ω^n&=ω^{n\bmod 5}
\end{aligned}
$$

The roots can be obtained by:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
ζ_1\\ζ_2\\ζ_3\\ζ_4\\
\end{bmatrix}=
11\begin{bmatrix}
1 & ω   & ω^4 & ω^2 \\
1 & ω^2 & ω^3 & ω^4 \\
1 & ω^3 & ω^2 & ω \\
1 & ω^4 & ω   & ω^3 \\
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
-6\\35\\10\\20\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So the solution of the original quintic equation are:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
ω^4 & ω   & ω^4 & ω   \\
ω   & 1   & 1   & ω^4 \\
1   & ω^3 & ω^2 & 1   \\
ω^3 & ω^4 & ω   & ω^2 \\
ω^2 & ω^2 & ω^3 & ω^3 \\
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt[5]{ζ_1} \\
\sqrt[5]{ζ_2} \\
\sqrt[5]{ζ_3} \\
\sqrt[5]{ζ_4} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos\left(\frac{2kπ}{11}\right) = \frac{1}{10}\left(x_k-1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

where

$$
ω^k = \cos\left(\frac{2kπ}{5}\right)
+\sqrt{\cos ^2\left(\frac{2kπ}{5}\right)-1}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
ω^0 &= 1 \\
ω^1 &=+\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1+i\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ω^2 &=-\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1-i\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ω^3 &=-\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1+i\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ω^4 &=+\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1-i\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
ζ_1&=-\frac{11}{4} \left(89-25 \sqrt{5}-5 i \sqrt{410+178 \sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ζ_2&=-\frac{11}{4} \left(89+25 \sqrt{5}+5 i \sqrt{410-178 \sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ζ_3&=-\frac{11}{4} \left(89+25 \sqrt{5}-5 i \sqrt{410-178 \sqrt{5}}\right) \\
ζ_4&=-\frac{11}{4} \left(89-25 \sqrt{5}+5 i \sqrt{410+178 \sqrt{5}}\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Your $\zeta_1$ can be factored into ***two*** quartic roots. Kindly see third answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that, since that quintic has a cyclic Galois group, $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{11}$ can be expressed in terms of radicals. However, the expression is quite complicated. Wolfram's has a function called $\texttt{ToRadicals[]}$ that does the job. In this case, $\cos\frac{2\pi}{11} = A/B$, where

\begin{align*}
A &= 116\ 2^{4/5} 11^{2/5}-4\ 2^{4/5} \sqrt{5} 11^{2/5}-40 i 2^{3/10} 11^{2/5} \sqrt{5\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\\
&-2\ 2^{3/5} 11^{4/5} \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{2/5}\\
&+2\ 2^{3/5}\sqrt{5} 11^{4/5} \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i\sqrt{10\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{2/5}\\
&-8 \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{3/5}\\
&-2^{2/5}\sqrt[5]{11} \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{4/5}\\
&+2^{2/5} \sqrt{5} \sqrt[5]{11} \left(-178-50\sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10\left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{4/5}\\
&-36\ 11^{3/5} \sqrt[5]{2 i \left(178 i+50 i
   \sqrt{5}-65 \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 \sqrt{10
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)}\\
&+4 \sqrt{5} 11^{3/5} \sqrt[5]{2 i \left(178 i+50 i
   \sqrt{5}-65 \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 \sqrt{10
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)}\\
&+i \sqrt[10]{2} \sqrt[5]{11} \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}\Bigg( \\
&16
   \sqrt[5]{22}-12\ 2^{3/5} 11^{2/5} \sqrt[5]{-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}}\\
&-4\ 11^{3/5}
   \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{2/5}\\
&+\left(2 \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i \sqrt{2
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10
   \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right)^{4/5}\\
&\Bigg)\\
\end{align*}

and

$B = 80 \left(-178-50 \sqrt{5}-65 i
   \sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}+25 i \sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)^{3/5}.$

Comment: +1 Now for the next problem: find a simple geometric construction to prove this is the exact value!

Comment: @TheoBendit +1 for Wolfram! All I can say is that, numerically, this expression coincides with $\cos \frac{2\pi}{11}$ within machine precision.

Answer (score 2):

The strange thing I've observed about some cyclic $5$-degs and $7$-degs (I'm not yet certain about the extent of this phenomenon) is that their resolvents *can be factored*. To factor a small composite integer is trivial, but to factor one quartic root into *two* quartic roots (or one sextic root into three sextic roots) is not easy.

For example, given the OP's

$$Z_1=-\frac{11}{4} \left(89-25 \sqrt{5}-5 \sqrt{-(410+178 \sqrt{5})}\right)$$

then we have the factorization,

$$-Z_1 = \frac{ab}{11}$$

$$a=\frac{11}{4}\left(-1+5\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{-10(5+\sqrt{5})}\right)$$

$$b=\frac{11}{4}\left(-31+5\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{-10(85+31\sqrt{5})}\right)$$

and we can use this factorization to solve, in an alternative manner, the minimal polynomial of $x=2\cos(2\pi/11)$ namely,

$$x^5 +x^4 −4x^3 −3x^2 +3x+1 = 0$$

Let $\beta_k = \big({-Z_1}\big)^{1/5}\, \zeta_5^k,\;$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4.$ Then the five roots are,

$$x_k = -\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{\beta_k^{-1}}+\frac{1}{\beta_k^0}+\frac{11}{\beta_k^1}+\frac{a}{\beta_k^2}+\frac{b}{\beta_k^3} \right)$$

with fifth root of unity $\zeta_5 = e^{2\pi\,i/5}.$

---

**P.S.** Thus, we only need ***one*** root of the resolvent quartic, and ***one*** fifth root extraction instead of the four in the usual method,

$$x = \frac15\left(A+Z_1^{1/5}+Z_2^{1/5}+Z_3^{1/5}+Z_4^{1/5}\right)$$

which can lead to an ambiguous real value when all the $Z_i$ are complex. For a similar solution for the case $p=31$ of $2\cos(2\pi/p)$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1339017/4781).